# sending an email without being traced (IP, identity)

Tags: email, ip, anonymity

I want to send an email through Gmail without the other side being able to trace me. I actually want to report something. I opened up a new Gmail account with a fake name (I used Tor to log in). I did have to verify the cell phone number, but I did buy a new SIM card that I never used before. I did all this at my home.

What else can I do to protect myself from someone figuring out my identity?

Comment: It depends on the someone and their resources. How did you purchase the phone, and the SIM, and the Service? What identification did you provide? Using the phone locates you to a relatively small area, very small if GPS functioned.  I'm surprised you are able to get Gmail to work with Tor.

Comment: well, it is a large company, but not an IT company even though they probably have IT people working there. I bought a phone through my company few years ago. SIM i bought at the news stand (no name required, random number given). i managed to open up a gmail account because i provided the cell phone number (the one i bought and never used). will i still be traceable if i remove the card now that i used it for the purpose of registering the gmail?

Comment: i didn't plan on using the phone to send this email (information). i plan on using my laptop, using gmail opened through TOR, and will use TOR to send this email also. can someone find my IP if i use TOR (gmail) to send it through?

Comment: Who do you want to be anonymous from? The large company? They will not be able to get any info about you from the Gmail service, so there is nothing more you need to do (and you've gone overboard with what you've done).

Comment: yes, this large company with a very influential owner. i live in the former soviet union so i must be very careful. anyways, i mean, if i send it from home (all the coffee shops are closed due to covid) and use TOR to send gmail email, you think i cant be traced? thank you in advance. i am not an IT person.just a little paranoid.

Comment: As an alternative, if you only need to send and don't need a reply, a Mixmaster type II remailer might be worth considering. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_remailer